# StackOverflow exception occurs when StartCopyAsync is invoked

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I'm writing a console app that makes a copy of a given blob with code similar to this:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

var sourceBlob1 = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("SOURCE1.txt");
var targetBlob1 = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("TARGET1.txt");
await targetBlob1.StartCopyAsync(sourceBlob1, null, null, null, null, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

var sourceBlob2 = blobContainer.GetPageBlobReference("SOURCE2.txt");
var targetBlob2 = blobContainer.GetPageBlobReference("TARGET2.txt");
await targetBlob2.StartCopyAsync(sourceBlob2, null, null, null, null, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The app copies the block blob successfully but it crashes with a StackOverflow exception when trying to copy the page blob.

Any idea why I'm getting a StackOverflow exception when copying the page blob but not when copying the block blob?

EDIT: I created a simple console app to reproduce the issue. Here's program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

            var sourceBlob = blobContainer.GetPageBlobReference("SOURCE.txt");
            var targetBlob = blobContainer.GetPageBlobReference("TARGET.txt");
            targetBlob.StartCopyAsync(sourceBlob, null, null, null, null, CancellationToken.None).Wait();

        }
    }
}
```

and here's ConsoleApp1.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="8.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and here's the result when I run this console app:
[image]

The output window in Visual Studio shows the following:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll

Comment: Yes, there's a reason a StackOverflowException would prevent you from copying a page blob: It would crash the application. I suggest you figure out what's recursing, and stop it from doing that.

Comment: Almost always, these days (in C#), it seems to be because you're writing an extension method and, rather than calling into the real class methods you accidentally call yourself. Without more code context here, I cannot be sure, but that's what I'd expect 80% of times.

Comment: There aren't really many causes of stack overflows, beyond unbounded recursion. Which involves method calls that we can see. Which means showing us code from (I'm guessing) a single method won't help us to help you to identify the cause. We need to see, *at the least*, the formal signature of the current method in which this code exists.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what baffles me is that the exception occurs on the "StartCopyAsync" call which is from the Azure SDK and therefore I don't have visibility what's happening. I'll try to put together a complete app to reproduce rather than just code snippet.

Comment: @desautelsj Seriously though, as Damian says, the answer is pretty much certain to involve something recursing infinitely, so the answer has to involve figuring out what's doing that and why. Without more code, the best we can do is offer wild guesses, which are worth very little. My first wild guess is that you've got two objects referencing each other, so the object graph is effectively infinite.

Comment: What's frustrating is that I can't catch the exception and look at the stack trace to figure out what is recursing infinitely.

Comment: There's a phrase that I'd recommend that you spend a while reading up on (if you have the time to spare) - "Select isn't broken" - i.e. the odds that a *framework* method contains a *gratuitous* bug that nobody before you has spotted is highly unlikely. So you need to work hard on the [mcve] and *prove* that it's not your code that's broken. I.e. (2) it's unlikely that `StartCopyAsync`, itself, is the source of the fault

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't interpret OP's question as suggesting that the bug was actually in `StartCopyAsync`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - read the title again

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I read the title, the question, and OP's comments.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - Agreed - so their first assertion, in the title, is that a framework method is broken. They then wander about a bit in the question and comments, but they still *fundamentally believe* that the fault is in the core code - "from the Azure SDK and therefore I don't have visibility". I'm *trying* to motivate them to inspect their own code - what are you trying to do?

Comment: You can attach a debugger, then run until exception happens, then open "call stack" window in Visual Studio and look at the call stack. That might give you more information about the problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was trying to point out that the exception occurs when invoking StartCopy, I wasn’t implying there is a bug in the SDK. Nonetheless, I will edit the title to remove any doubt.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was trying to steer somebody away from jumping to conclusions.

Comment: I have created a very simple console app which reproduces the issue (see link in updated question).

Comment: @EdPlunkett Done. Question updated with code.

Comment: It seems that you were downvoted for no reason and this is indeed bug in azure library, because function you call indeed mistakenly calls itself (and so - always fails with StackOverflow exception, no matter what). I'd suggest to file an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues with your reproducable example and link to this question (optionally).

Comment: @Evk thanks. I have opened an issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/597

Comment: It's too bad my question was down voted when it turns out I have indeed discovered a bug in the SDK.

Comment: @desautelsj Unfortunately clueless downvotes are like serial downvotes — just part of the deal. Nothing you can do. You can at least enjoy the complex and nuanced irony of Damien’s contributions.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Ironic indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response from a Microsoft person on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/597) I opened last night: they acknowledge this problem is a regression bug in Azure Storage SDK.

While we wait for the issue to be fixed, they suggest working around it by using a different overload of the [StartCopyAsync](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/WindowsRuntime/Blob/CloudPageBlob.cs#L1230) method. But also, as @tom-sun suggests, I could downgrade to an earlier version of the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is [Azure storage SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) issue. I also can reproduce it on my side with **WindowsAzure.Storage version >= 8.2.0.**

If downgrade  the Azure storage SDK version is possible, please use the [Azure SDK version 8.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/8.1.4), then it will work as expected.